# How to properly use RcppThread to parallelize a for-loop

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to parallelize a for loop with RcppThread. The unparallelized version looks like this:

```
IntegerVector simulate_pos(NumericVector x_pop,
                           NumericVector y_pop,
                           int n_studies,
                           int sample_size_min,
                           int sample_size_max,
                           bool replace,
                           float lower_limit,
                           float upper_limit){
  IntegerVector pos(n_studies);
  int npop = x_pop.size();
  NumericVector index_pop(npop);
  for (int i = 0; i < npop; i++){
    index_pop[i] = i;
  }

  // HERE IS THE LOOP-------------------------------------------------
  for (int k = 0; k < n_studies; k++){
    pos[k] = simulate_one_pos(x_pop, y_pop, index_pop, sample_size_min,
                              sample_size_max, replace, lower_limit,
                              upper_limit);
  }
  // ------------------------------------------------------------------

  return(pos);
}
```

Now I thought it would be no problem to use parallelFor:

```
std::vector<int> simulate_pos(NumericVector x_pop,
                              NumericVector y_pop,
                              int n_studies,
                              int sample_size_min,
                              int sample_size_max,
                              bool replace,
                              float lower_limit,
                              float upper_limit,
                              int n_threads){
  std::vector<int> pos(n_studies);
  int npop = x_pop.size();
  NumericVector index_pop(npop);
  for (int i = 0; i < npop; i++){
    index_pop[i] = i;
  }
  
  // HERE IS THE LOOP-------------------------------------------------
  RcppThread::parallelFor(0, pos.size(), [&] (int i){
    pos[i] = simulate_one_pos(x_pop, y_pop, index_pop, sample_size_min,
                              sample_size_max, replace, lower_limit,
                              upper_limit);
  });
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------

  return(pos);
}
```

To stick to the RcppThread-paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.00450.pdf) I used an `std::vector` as the return value instead of the Rcpp equivalent `IntegerVector`.

Sometimes the code works, sometimes I get a stack imbalance error, sometimes it just hangs. I assume that I am making a big conceptual mistake and have to note that I am pretty much a noob at C++.

Is the problem that several threads are reading the same memory address at the same time? Or are the Rcpp data structures (e.g. NumericVector) causing issues?

The complete code can be found on github: https://github.com/johannes-titz/fastpos/tree/rcppthread

To run for yourself:

```
devtools::install_github("johannes-titz/fastpos@rcppthread")

pop <- fastpos::create_pop(0.5, 1e5)
x <- pop[,1]
y <- pop[,2]
lower_limit <- 0.4
upper_limit <- 0.6
n_studies <- 50
sample_size_min <- 20
sample_size_max <- 1000

res <- fastpos::simulate_pos(x, y, n_studies, sample_size_min, sample_size_max, TRUE, lower_limit,
                             upper_limit, 4)
```

PS: also tried to use `pool.pushReturn`, but with the same outcome.

EDIT: The problem was indeed using Rcpp data structures (`NumericVector`). When replacing all of them with `std::vector` it runs fine. Now, without the Rcpp sugar, I had to find a way how to sample from a `std::vector` (inside the function I call in the loop), but this is obviously worth it.

Comment: A crucial part that you are not showing is the definition of `simulate_one_pos`. Additionally, as @Dirk points out, starting with a smaller example can pay great dividends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write

> Is the problem that several threads are reading the same memory address at the same time? Or are the Rcpp data structures (e.g. NumericVector) causing issues?

and I am inclined to say "likely". See the excellent documentation in package RcppParallel, and how it builds up from small examples.

I know this sounds unappealing but I really recommending building from a *really small function* with maybe zero or one arguments slowly adding and making sure that when you cross the bridge of adding *any* R-accessible or created memory that things still work as intended.

Sadly, we can't slap a parallel outer loop around inner R code and "hope for the best".  OpenMP and friends are more demanding, and R's single-threaded nature imposes more constraints.

(And you probably know one can of course run higher-level parallelism from R over R functions, but that is a different topic and approach.)

Comment: Thank you very much! I do not use higher-level parallelism because I want some kind of progress indicator (the simulation runs quite long). Adding to a smaller function makes sense, but the problem for me lies in how to test it properly. Sometimes the code would just run a dozen times without errors and then break again, although I did not change anything. It is somewhat unpredictable to me. I guess it is best to not mess with it at my level of experience, but I will at least try to get rid of the Rcpp data structures. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that is an "added excitement": the errors don't always show.  The safest bet is to explicitly use non-R/non-Rcpp data structures ... at the cost of copies at beginning and end.

Comment: I like this attitude ("added excitement"), it is good to see passion. The problem was indeed using Rcpp data structures, I replaced them and now it runs just fine.

Comment: Yay!  Any hunch as to what the cost of copying at begind and end is?  "Ignorable" ?  (And please feel free to upvote and/or accept to make the karma go around...)

Comment: I could do it without Rcpp data structures. But unfortunately there seems to be too much overhead in general, singlethreaded is actually faster. ☉_☉ I settled on a simpler solution that I can control better, I use futures in R to run several simulations in the background, meanwhile the main R process starts another simulation with a progessbar in cpp. Obviously all simulations end at similar times. I get the speed benefit and a progressbar without "added excitement".